# What is the word called which is sad about ending but also happy for good things happened in the way

Tags: single-word-requests

I felt that feeling in avengers endgame movie, I was sad about retiring Avengers but satisfied about good things happened in the way

Comment: I can't think of a single word to express all that! You could say it left you with mixed emotions.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that "Early Modern English was used from the late 15th century to the mid to late 17th century." (Hover your cursor over the tag.) Please consider editing your tag for this question.

Comment: @KateBunting Don’t you think _bittersweet_ expresses it quite well? I mean, its definition is obviously not a precise as this description, with ‘sad ending but good things along the way’ exactly, but it’s pretty close to me.

Comment: To paraphrase the White Knight,the word is called Cecil. What the word *is* is another question.

Answer (score 5):

I think "bittersweet" fits. Merriam-Webster: "pleasure accompanied by suffering or regret" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bittersweet

Answer (score 0):

a **silver lining**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/silver+lining)  n.

> a comforting or hopeful aspect of an otherwise desperate or unhappy
>   situation

As in:

I felt that feeling in *Avengers Endgame* movie: I was sad about retiring them.  But the **silver lining** was the satisfaction about the good things that happened.